# Prevent focus on field when it fails validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I often use [this jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to validate forms and it works great. Really pleased with it, but when you press Submit on a form it automatically puts focus on the field that was invalid.

On my current project I have a form wich is really long, and when you press the submit button, your scroll jumps up to the field (probably because it gets focused), but when my form is this long i think it's a bit annoying. Does anyone know how i can disable jQuery validate from putting focus on invalid input fields.

Best regards!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `focusInvalid` option and set it to `false` :

```
$("#abc").validate({
  focusInvalid: false
});
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/QPxFe/345/) and [Documentation here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) (options tab)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#frmTableDate').validationEngine({ focusFirstField: false });
```

in case we are using Validation Engine plugin to validate

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#myform").validate({
onfocusout: false,
invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errors) {                    
        validator.errorList[0].element.focus();
    }
} 
});
```

Answer (score -4):

1. Go to your jQuery validate file file (http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js)
2. Use Control and F to find
3. Remove  `.focus()` on line 431.

Comment: No No No ... why edit the code when there is a perfectly good option - there are SOOO many reasons why this is a poor idea